# Rubik's cube $5 \times 5 \times 5$ numbered arrangement

Tags: rubiks-cube

If you take a $5 \times 5 \times 5$ cube and enumerate each little square with a number, following an ascending order, then scramble it, how many possibilities you have to solve it? With all numbers in order and same rotation as initial.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "how many possibilities you have to solve it", either "1, obviously", or "infinitely many, obviously". Perhaps you could clarify what you mean.

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange. A quick tour of the site (https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most of your time here.